# WiX Minimal UI shows first lines empty with Arabic text

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7, wix-extension

I'm using `WiX 3.7` I managed to get `WiX Minimal UI` to work properly following the instructions from http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_dialog_library.html

When I used Arabic Licence file is shown incorrectly (first lines are blank), unless user scrolls the text area in which case the text starts to look as expected.

I already tried the advice from the page http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html

- Open your RTF file in WordPad and save it from there in order to remove the complex RTF content from the file. After saving it, rebuild your MSI.

My current approach is to write a `Custom EULA Dialog`, but I would prefer to stay with WiX UI Minimal builtin Dialog... Have you experienced this problem? Do you know how to overcome it?